# Tag for geographic information

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

We have a fair number of questions involving geographic information; a search for `CountryData` returns 19 hits alone and there are other examples of questions concerning maps in one form or another.  Most of these have the [curated-data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curated-data) tag.  I wonder if we should have some more specific tag concerning [geography](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography)?  We have a [geodesy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geodesy) tag, but that is really something different from most of these questions.

Comment: spatial? or geography?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me. Yes, [tag:geography] and [tag:geodesy] are separate subjects.

Comment: I like geography, myself.  If a few others chime in positively, then I'll add it.

Comment: I also approve `geography` so long as the question actually is about geography and not just e.g. list-processing.  I'll help tag if you ask, otherwise have at it.

Comment: OK, sounds sufficient.  I've never created a tag before so I'll give it a try.

Comment: I already wrote a tag description for starters. If you've got additions/edits, put them in!

Comment: Ahh... I forgot the description!  Like I said, it's my first tag.  Thanks, I'll take a look.

Comment: I don't think we need the `geodesy` tag. Not only has it only been used once, the *word* "geodesy" doesn't appear in any other question, and probably never will either. So far the word "geography" only appears twice, but I think that is a better tag candidate than `geodesy`.

Comment: I'm closing this, because otherwise the [Community ♦](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user will keep bumping this to the top of the list every couple of weeks even though it is resolved :)